# JScrollPane shows graphics glitches on row header. How to avoid this?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, java-2d

I'm trying to use a `JScrollPane` with a column header and a row header.

On the rowheader, there is some text. When I scroll down the pane, some graphics artifacts appear on the rowheader. It's like the bottom line of pixels is repeated once and again.

The problem is solved if I maximize and restore the main window, but it's not the way it should be.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: The problem is with the custom painting code of your row header. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: A guess: if you do custom painting in the row header, do you call the super method in the paint method? In other words, if you override paint, do  you call `super.paint(g)`? and likewise for paintComponent/super.paintComponent. And I agree with camickr, please show us an SSCCE if this doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. There was something in the custom paint code. I fixed it adding a line setting the preferred size of the component.

Answer (score 0):

I find that glitches like this are usually caused by custom `paint()` methods or not repainting after you make changes.

First, I always call as the first line in my custom paint method.

```
super.paint();  or  super.paintComponent(g);
```

I also find that these two lines keep everything fresh and up to date.  They might be time consuming, but they have solved a lot of problems.  I usually put them at the end of code that modifies the view.

```
this.validate();
this.repaint();
```

Comment: doctoring on symptons by random method calling is _not_ recommended - instead, find the error and fix it